# Ruby: Iterating Over Array Based on Following Elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, for-loop

I am creating a week-by-week report of meetings using Ruby.  I have a large array that contains the names of the meetings, and I have multiple instances of each element based on how many weeks they occured.

Simplified example I am starting with:

```
meetingsArray = ["boardInvestorsMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat",  "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat"]
```

My attempt:

```
meetingsArray = ["boardInvestorsMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat",  "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat"]
for m in meetingsArray[m.to_i]
  if (meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 1] && meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 2] && meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 3])
    puts "Week of the 1st: " + "#{meetingsArray[m.to_i].inject{|a| a}}"
  elsif (meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 1] && meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 2])
    puts "Week of the 8th: " + "#{meetingsArray[m.to_i].inject{|a| a}}"
  elsif (meetingsArray[m.to_i] === meetingsArray[(m.to_i) + 1])
    puts "Week of the 15th: " + "#{meetingsArray[m.to_i].inject{|a| a}}"
  else
    puts "Week of the 22nd: " + "#{meetingsArray[m.to_i].inject{|a| a}}"
  end
end
```

Console error:

```
iMac:workspace user1$ ruby loop.rb
loop.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for "boardInvestorsMeeting":String (NoMethodError)
```

Desired results:

```
Week of the 1st: boardInvestorsMeeting
Week of the 1st: clientMeeting
Week of the 8th: clientMeeting
Week of the 15th: clientMeeting
Week of the 1st: waterCoolerChat
Week of the 8th: waterCoolerChat
Week of the 15th: waterCoolerChat
Week of the 22nd: waterCoolerChat
```

Note that `"clientMeeting"` has `"Week of the 1st:"` then `"Week of the 8th:"` then `"Week of the 15th:"` in front of it because is repeated twice; while `"boardInvestorsMeeting"` only has `"Week of the 1st:"` in front of it because it isn't repeated and only appears in `meetingsArray` once.

Comment: It is not clear which part is what you start with, which part is your expected result, and which part is your attempt.

Comment: @undur_gongor I made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: @sawa I just restructured my question based on your recommendations.

Comment: Your code doesn't run at all. Can you edit your question to include the actual code you're using? It fails on the first line, because you're not using `for` correctly. Please edit your question to include the code that produces the results you say you're getting.

Comment: @Jordan I edited the question to reflect the code I am getting.  I can't see how I am using the for loop incorrectly and when I replace the `if` statement inside to just `puts` the `meetingsArray` I get no errors.

Comment: Copying and pasting your code under "My attempt:" produces the error ``undefined method `each' for "boardInvestorsMeeting":String (NoMethodError)``. Take a look: http://ideone.com/5eEAiq In `for m in meetingsArray[m.to_i]`, `m.to_i` evaluates to `0` (because `m` has been initialized to `nil`, and `nil.to_i` is `0`, and `meetingsArray[0]` is the string `"boardInvestorsMeeting"`). A correct use of `for` would be `for m in meetingsArray`, but `for` is unidiomatic in Ruby. Generally you should use `Enumerable#each` instead, e.g. `meetingsArray.each do |meeting| ... end`.

Comment: @Jordan I was trying to use the index of the array when determining how many duplicates to create using a loop.  I did try using the `meetingsArray.each do |meeting| ... end` syntax but received an error as well.  I should've just used a hash instead, like @JonahR did.

Comment: If you want to iterate over an array along with its indices, that's what `Enumerable#each_with_index` is for.

Comment: @Jordan you're right, but I just couldn't get the syntax down.  Thank you for an alternative solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
meetingsArray = ["boardInvestorsMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "clientMeeting", "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat",  "waterCoolerChat", "waterCoolerChat"]
counts = Hash.new(0)
meetingsArray.each { |name| counts[name] += 1 }

counts.each do |k,v|
    case v
    when 1
        puts "Week of the 1st: #{k}" 
    when 2
        puts "Week of the 1st: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 8th: #{k}"
    when 3
        puts "Week of the 1st: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 8th: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 15th: #{k}"
    when 4
        puts "Week of the 1st: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 8th: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 15th: #{k}"
        puts "Week of the 22nd: #{k}"
    end
end
```

Comment: Clean and easy way to attack my problem.  Thank you.